vscode w/python extension and virtual environments: do the paths in pyenv.cfg and the paths identified in .venv to python.exe need to match?
folks,
newbie question learning  'PATH' in win10 environment variables, 'PATH' in the pyenv.cfg, and 'PATH' when you look at the .venv in a project directory and see the path to python.exe.

i have 3 directories as i learn python from 3 different texts.
2 directories were set up and use python 3.12.3; 1 directory to be built next will use python 3.8.1
when i did initial python download, used to create each of the venvs, it was loaded to AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312
if i look at pyenv.cfg,  the 'home' specifies AppData location
if i look at .venv, i see python.exe 'PATH' as ...my author's text/.venv/Scripts/python

question: do the paths in windows environment variables, pyenv.cfg and .venv all have to match?
question: when i download/install python 3.8.1, where will it go? AppData? will that be in pyenv.cfg?
question: and if i have 2 modules in one of the project directories [1 module has code, the other moduloe imports pyTest and has tests for that code], i keep getting 'module not found' error when the pyTest module tries to find the code module? could that be because i don't understand these path issues?
thanks for any education
i am bogged down on all this 'path' stuff, very important, but stopped learning python to explore all these path concerns
thanks for any help,
ron
question:

you can understand it this way:

The paths in pyenv.cfg and .venv don't have to match exactly. The pyenv.cfg file is the interpreter version used to configure the virtual environment,.venv is a directory that is created under the project when you create a Venv virtual environment.
When installing Python 3.8.1, it is installed under C:\Users\MYL(your username)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python by default, of course, you can also customize the path when installing.
Getting a "module not found" error with a different module, it could because of python's environment variables. You can search for path and select system environment on your computer to find out if there is a python version of the path. If not, select New to add the python path.
If you use import from.import module, you need to check if the __init__.py file exists in the src and tests folders.

You can learn more about the python interpreter installation by the document.
